# Cannot address heteroscedasticity in LMM (nlme R)

Tags: r, mixed-models, nlme

I'm trying to build a linear mixed model in R using nlme. My response variable is distributed like that:
[image]

My final model presents a lot of heteroscedasticity and I cannot find a solution to correct it.
The model is something like :

```
lme(mass ~ n_boat + n_spec + breeding_stage*season,
                random = list(ID = ~1),
                data = my_data)
```

and the variance of residuals looks like that :
[image]

The issue seems to come from the n_boat variable :
[image]

I tried using different variance structure to correct that effect, but none seems to work properly. Here is and example with `varFixed`

```
var_fix <- varFixed(~n_boat)
lme(mass ~ n_boat + n_spec + breeding_stage*season,
                    random = list(ID = ~1),
                    data = my_data,
                    weights = var_fix)
```

[image]

I also tried log transforming my response variable with no results.
How should I address this issue ? Shall I do something with the data before the model ? I'm a bit lost at this point.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: A mass can't be negative. Why do you have negative masses in your data? I don't think heteroscedasticity is your main issue.

Comment: It is mass variation, some values are negative, and it's normal, but it's a small part of the dataset

Comment: Looking at the plots, they seem to indicate some "soft" lower and upper limits to the DV. It looks like it can't be much below zero or above 600.